# How I Create Excel Workbook with Syncfusion XLSIO from Uint8list or File in Flutter?

Tags: excel, flutter, import, syncfusion, filepicker

I got the Excel file from file-picker as Uint8list, and convert to it File now:

```
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles( type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'], );

 if (result != null) 

{ var file = File.fromRawPath(result.files.single.bytes);

}
```

How I convert it to a Syncfusion XLSIO workbook (fromUint8list or File) for reading data from sheet 0 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we don't have support to read Excel using Flutter XlsIO library.

However, you can create Excel files using "syncfusion_flutter_xlsio" library with the following features.

1. Create a simple Excel document
2. Add text, number, and datetime values
3. Add formulas
4. Apply formatting
5. Add images
6. Add charts
7. Add hyperlinks to texts and images
8. Protect workbooks and worksheets
9. AutoFit rows and columns
10. Insert or delete rows and columns
11. Apply conditional formatting

To know more about the "syncfusion_flutter_xlsio" library please refer the following link.
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio